# How do you prove that a function is an injective/surjective function?

Tags: calculus, functions

Basically I know that $$(f◦g)(x)=x$$ (from R to R for any x in R)

How do I show that $f$ or $g$ are injective? and how do I show that they are surjective?

Comment: Assume that $g(x) = g(y)$. Apply $f$ to both sides... What have you shown?

Comment: @Myself and how do you prove surjective?

Comment: @Myself actually both of them are not injective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: I claim that $g$ is injective. For this, suppose that $g(x)=g(y)$. Then $f(g(x))=f(g(y))$, i.e. $x=y$. Thus $g$ is injective.

Second: I claim that $f$ is surjective. To see this, take any $y\in\mathbb R$. Define $z := g(y)$. Then it is true that $f(z)=f(g(y))=y$. Because $y$ was arbitrary, $f$ is surjective.

Finally: I claim that $g$ need not be surjective and $f$ need not be injective. To see this, consider the following functions:
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x-1 & x\in\mathbb Z \text{ and } x\geq 0 \\ x & x\in\mathbb Z \text{ and } x < 0 \\ x & x\in\mathbb R \setminus\mathbb Z\end{cases}, $$
$$ g(x) = \begin{cases} x+1 & x\in\mathbb Z \text{ and } x\geq 0 \\ x & x\in\mathbb Z \text{ and } x < 0 \\ x & x\in\mathbb R \setminus\mathbb Z\end{cases}, $$
Then it is easy to verify that $f(g(x))=x$ for all $x$. But note that $f$ is not injective because $f(0) = f(-1) = 0$ and that $g$ is not surjective, because there is no $z$ such that $g(z)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

First look at the definitions.
By definition.

A function , $f:X→Y$ is injective or one to one if

$\forall x_{1}, x_{2} \in X, ( x_{1}\neq x_2  \Rightarrow f(x_{1}) \neq f(x_{2})). $

And a function $f:X→Y$ is called surjective/onto if

$\forall y \in Y, \exists x \in X, y = f(x). $